# Not Rendering properly "UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions"

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I'm just taking a signature and saving with imageMask .  Here actually the imageMask rendering  properly but the main signature behaves abnormally like 2 lines of it.
Here is my code .

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0); //retina res
    [self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    [imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 703, 273)];
    [maskImages.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.2];
    [lblAckNo drawTextInRect:CGRectMake(320, 230,100,50)];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    NSData *imgData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSString *jpgPath = @"/Users/kumaralakshmanna/Pictures/Test.jpg";
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

Here is the screenshots of it.[image: Before Saving] && This is what I'm getting -[image: After Saved]

Any Solution to overcome from this issue .? Thanks.

Comment: And the problem is? Where those three images come from?

Comment: There are 2 images , In the 1st one, I'm putting signature When I hit "OK" It Captures and shown up , there itself I added one UIImage as Mask.
2nd one showing after I hit "Agree & Submit " It saves .

Comment: The 1st one is the Signature View , It uses some graphics to take some drawing . After I hit , it saves perfectly.  When I'm going to save with maskImage ..I'm getting the image like this.

Comment: Are you copying and printing the signature in the same `CGSize`? Maybe the second one is a bit smaller.

Comment: Just added an "official" answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are drawing using the same `CGSize`. You are probably using two different size to capture the image and to draw it, so it gets stretched.